# Mac MS-Dos Partitioning Error

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I am running a late 2012 iMac with 3tb fusion drive and 32gb of ram. In order to play minecraft and halo with my sister, i wanted to install windows via Bootcamp, however, when it came to the partition stage it wouldn't let me select a size less than 1tb, even tho I only have 800GB available and only wanted to allocate around 100gb anyway,  Because of this, I tried to install it without Bootcamp and have made a mess of my hard drive. Following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0XtZjuMTNk&ab_channel=HeadsofTechnology) I attempted to create an MS-Dos partition on my mac, but it was stuck on something like 'resizing core storage physical volume structures' for a good few minutes. I read that it shouldn't really take more than 2 mins to create a partition and assumed it had crashed. I waited around 10 mins and nothing happened, so I forced quit disk utility and rebooted my mac.

My machine seems to be usable, and is not as yet having any issues - the only thing is that the 125GB that I had allocated for the Windows partition is gone. There is no partition showing in disk utility, but my drive's available space is 125gb less than it was. I have tried running first aid, but it has not changed anything.

At this point - I think I just want to recover the space and forget windows all together - how do I do that - is it possible to do without reformatting? is it possible I could lose data with my drive as it is now?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Output from the command `diskutil list`:

```
Last login: Mon Dec 28 11:56:37 on console
James-Richardsons-iMac:~ jamesrichardson$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            3.0 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +3.0 TB     disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 95D9EC18-33C9-40FD-917D-5856017AD2A0
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive

James-Richardsons-iMac:~ jamesrichardson$
```

Comment: Post to your question, the output from `diskutil list`. Also, what version of macOS are you using?

Comment: Hi there,Thank you for your reply - I am using High SIerra. I could not add the diskutil output to my comment so have put it in my original post. Thanks again.